# The dimension of parameter space of unstable Higgs bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces

Let $X$:smooth projective curve of genus $g\geq 3$ over $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathcal{M}(r,d)$:moduli space of stable Higgs bundles of rank $r\geq 2$ and degree $d$ on $X$, and $N$:moduli space of stable vector bundles.

There is a stratification of $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{M}(r,d)$ by the Harder–Narasimhan type,
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle \mathcal{M}=\bigcup_{\lambda}U_{\lambda}
\end{equation*}
( $(E,\phi\colon E\rightarrow E\otimes K_{X})\in U_{\lambda}\Leftrightarrow $  the Harder–Narasimhan type of a vector bundle $E$ is $\lambda$. )
There is an open dense stratum $U_{d/r}$ corresponding to Higgs bundles $(E,\phi)$ for which the underlying vector bundle $E$ is itself stable. This represents the cotangent bundle of $N$, the moduli space of stable bundles.

I want to show the codimension of the complement of the cotangent bundle $U_{d/r}=T^{*}N\subseteq \mathcal{M}$ is at least 2.

So, wish to estimate the dimension of the space of stable Higgs bundles (underlying vector bundles are unstable) of the following type,
\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow F_{1}\rightarrow E\rightarrow F_{2}\rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
where $\mu(F_{1})>\mu(F_{2})$ and $F_{1}$ and $F_{2}$ are itself stable.

According to [Flat Connections and Geometric Quantization by N.J.Hitchin](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104200841), for each choice of bundle $E$ expressible as an extension in the above way, the extra parameter for stable Higgs field is $h^{0}(X,\operatorname{End}E\otimes K_{X})-h^{0}(X,\operatorname{End}E)$.

But this doesn't make sense to me and I have a trouble.
Thanks in advance.